What are the most influential journals in information geometry?
I am an undergraduate student majoring in math. I'm interested in studying information geometry in graduate school, so I'm looking into it. However, due to my lack of mathematical knowledge and English language skills, it's hard to find a community of scholars working in this field and what journals are publishing their work.  It's also hard to find researchers working on information geometry at universities in my country, so I'm not sure where to go next.  Is it a good decision for me to go into data science to study information geometry?

Your last question is really not one that people here can answer, since  we do not know your situation. It would be best to ask someone closer to you, in particular in your own department, who might be able to point you in the direction of someone with more knowledge, if they can't answer themselves. As for your title question, a good start is trying to find some highly cited papers in information geometry, and see where they were published. It's less journal that are influential, as papers, by the way. Please note that this question may well end up closed, ....

... so I point out that perhaps the people at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ might be better placed to answer your question if you are minded to be going into data science. See also the answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/326551/4177 from 5 years ago. Best of luck!

Thank you for your kind response. It was very helpful!

I cannot advise you whether or not to study information geometry, since that’s a personal decision. They are different fields but there is certainly some overlap between IG and data science, so a background in the former can be helpful for learning the latter.
However, I can give some suggestions about journals. The most directly relevant journal is Information Geometry, which was founded in 2018. This is really an interdisciplinary journal so some of the papers are traditional math papers and others are more akin to stats papers or some mixture.
Many papers in IG are also published in Entropy. However, this journal is a pay to publish journal and they request that referees submit their reports within 10 days or so. That’s not to say that there isn’t valuable work in Entropy. For instance, I am happy to recommend Frank Nielsen’s introduction to the subject. However, in my opinion there isn’t sufficient quality control so I personally do not publish or review for them.
Every other year, the Geometric Science of Information conference is held in France and they publish a conference proceedings. These papers are short (capped at 8 pages), but oftentimes these these will get expanded into a full paper which can be found elsewhere.
Among more traditional math journals, Schwachhöfer is an editor at Differential Geometry and its Applications so they will publish work in IG that is sufficiently mathematically focused.
Apart from these, there a number of eclectic resources. Every few years, people put together a book of collected papers, but so far as I can tell these don’t come out on a regular schedule. There have been some papers on IG in a number of other math journals. I know of several in Annals of Applied Probability and Probability Theory and Related Fields and I believe there are a few in JASA as well. All three of those (especially the latter) are extremely selective journals though, so it is not typical to see papers there.

I would strongly recommend against submitting, as a very junior person, to a journal that has the practices that Entropy has. It comes with the risk that people view papers published in there as not serious, when one has no other social capital/reputation to back up one's work. Any maths journal that asks for referee reports in 10 days cannot be doing due diligence on refereeing thoroughness.

I was trying to state things diplomatically, but I completely agree.
